# Moving code from ActionListener to main()

Tags: java, awt

### PROBLEM:

I have following code for the `java.awt.Button` :

```
Button btn = new Button("abcde");
btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->
{
    String s = btn.getLabel().toUpperCase();    
    btn.setLabel(s);    
});
```

I need to move the code inside `btn.addActionListener` to the `public static void main(String[] args)`, something like below (in pseudo code):

```
Button btn = new Button("abcde");
btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->
{
    notify_main()_that_button_had_been_clicked();  
});

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    block_until_button_clicked();

    String s = UI.getButton().getLabel();
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    UI.getButton().setLabel(s);
}
```

### RELEVANT INFORMATION :

I am aware that there are better solutions for GUI development, but I am restricted to using AWT for UI.

**I have no power to change the above, nor can I provide details about the real code due to legal restrictions.**

To remedy above, I am submitting the below MVCE. Please base your answers on it:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class ResponsiveUI extends Frame
{
    public final Button btn = new Button("abcde");

    public ResponsiveUI()
    {
        add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->
        {
            String s = btn.getLabel().toUpperCase();    
            btn.setLabel(s);    
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ResponsiveUI rui = new ResponsiveUI();
        rui.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        rui.setSize(250, 150);
        rui.setResizable(false);
        rui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

I have used Google extensively, and was able to find some useful links.

1. UI will run in the separate thread, which will make it responsive (I do not know how to `join()` it properly, though).
2. For signaling mechanism, `wait()` and `notify()` seem like the right way to go.
3. To set Button's text, I can use `EventQueue.InvokeAndWait`.
4. To get Button's text, I do not know what to do, but I have an ugly workaround.

Below is the modified MVCE :

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class ResponsiveUI extends Frame
{

    public final Object lock = new Object();  // POINT #2 : signaling mechanism
    public final Button btn = new Button("abcde");

    public ResponsiveUI()
    {
        add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->
        {
            // POINT #2 : signal the main() thread that button is clicked
            synchronized (lock)
            {
                lock.notify();
            } 
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ResponsiveUI rui = new ResponsiveUI();

        // POINT #1: put UI into separate thread, so we can keep it responsive
        // POINT #1: I still do not know how to properly join() (it works OK though)
        Runnable r = () ->
        {
            rui.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            rui.setSize(250, 150);
            rui.setResizable(false);
            rui.setVisible(true);
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);

        try
        {
            synchronized (rui.lock)    // POINT #2  
            {                          // POINT #2 
                rui.lock.wait();       // POINT #2 : wait for button press

                final Button b = new Button();  // POINT #4 : EventQueue uses final local variables
                                                // store text into temp button (ugly but works)
                EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() ->  // POINT #4
                {
                    b.setLabel(rui.btn.getLabel());  
                });
                // we could do all kind of things, but for illustrative purpose just transform text into upper case
                EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() ->    // POINT #3 :
                {
                    rui.btn.setLabel(b.getLabel().toUpperCase());

                });
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error : " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want the main thread to be notified when the [AWT] button is clicked and upon receipt of that notification, you want to change the text of that button's label.

I started with the code from your modified [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you posted in your question.

Here is my code with explanatory notes after it.

```java
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class ResponsiveUI extends Frame {
    private static String  btnTxt;
    public final Object lock = new Object();
    public final Button btn = new Button("abcde");

    public ResponsiveUI() {
        add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            synchronized (lock) {
                btnTxt = e.getActionCommand();
                lock.notifyAll();
            } 
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResponsiveUI rui = new ResponsiveUI();

        Runnable r = () -> {
            rui.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            rui.setSize(250, 150);
            rui.setResizable(false);
            rui.setVisible(true);
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
        synchronized (rui.lock) {
            try {
                rui.lock.wait();
                String newBtnTxt = btnTxt.toUpperCase();
                EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> rui.btn.setLabel(newBtnTxt));
            }
            catch (InterruptedException x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order for the GUI thread to notify the main thread, I agree with you that `wait()` and `notifyAll()` is the mechanism to use. I use `notifyAll()` rather than `notify()` to make sure that **all** the waiting threads are notified.

I use a shared variable `btnTxt` to transfer the text of the button's label between the GUI thread and the main thread.

By default, the *action command* of the `ActionEvent` is the text of the [AWT] button's label. Hence the use of method `getActionCommand()` in my `ActionListener` implementation.

All changes to the GUI must be executed on the GUI thread, so after creating the new text for the button's label in the main thread, I use method `invokeLater()` of class `java.awt.EventQueue` to actually change the button's label text.

You should be able to copy the above code as is, compile it and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public final Button btn = new Button("abcde");
```

to:

```
public static final Button btn = new Button("abcde");
```

and move:

```
btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
    String s = btn.getLabel().toUpperCase();
    btn.setLabel(s);
});
```

inside the main method.

Answer (score -1):

The general approach is that you need to share some lock or semaphore with both the `main` method and your `ActionListener` implementation. Once you have a shared semaphore, the `main` method can block (wait) upon the semaphore and the `ActionListener` can notify the semaphore.

In pseudocode:

```
Lock lock = new Lock();

Button btn = new Button("abcde");
btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    lock.notify();
});

public static void main(String[] args) {

    lock.waitUntilNotified();

    String s = UI.getButton().getLabel();
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    UI.getButton().setLabel(s);
}
```

I have left the exact semaphore implementation to you since the nature of your application will dictate which mechanism will work best. For example, maybe you want to use a simple object and call the `wait` and `notify` methods on it, or you can use a blocking queue if you need to perform processing on elements that are loaded into the queue (i.e., items are queued up and the button press signals that the queued up items should now be processed).

You can find information on how to implement the `wait` and `notify` approach here:

- [wait and notify() Methods in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify)
- [Guarded Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Sharing the lock may be difficult since passing in the lock as a method argument is not an option in the `main` method. A simple approach (that would not be the first choice outside of this context) is creating the lock as a `static` variable:

```
public class Application {

    public static final Lock LOCK = new Lock();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LOCK.waitUntilNotified();

        String s = UI.getButton().getLabel();
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        UI.getButton().setLabel(s);
    }
}
```

In some other class:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    public void doSomething() {
        Button btn = new Button("abcde");
        btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            Application.LOCK.notify();
        });
    }
}
```

Bare in mind `Lock` is just pseudocode and should be replaced with whatever implementation of the lock that you decide to use.

Comment: I have started a bounty to draw more attention to this question. I would like to see more suggestions, if possible. If not, I have no problem awarding you the bounty, as a token of gratitude for the effort you made to help me.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to mess with threads in first place? Threading in an AWT/Swing application has some "conventions" and you seem to be far away from them.

Why don't you use a getter to access the button and the action listener in `main`'s layer?

First solution. Clean, and everyone is able to understand it (no `public static final` modifiers in an instance of a component)":

```
public class ResponsiveUI extends Frame {

    private Button button;

    public ResponsiveUI() {
        super("UI");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });

        button = new Button("something");
        add(button);
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            ResponsiveUI ui = new ResponsiveUI();

            Button button = ui.getButton();
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                button.setLabel(button.getLabel().toUpperCase());
            });

            ui.setSize(250, 150);
            ui.setResizable(false);
            ui.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Second solution, using some sort of dependency injection and avoid having a getter for the button:

```
public class ResponsiveUI extends Frame {

    private Button button;

    public ResponsiveUI(ActionListener buttonListener) {
        super("UI");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });

        button = new Button("something");
        button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        add(button);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            ActionListener changeLabelToUppercaseListener = e -> {
                Object source = e.getSource();
                if (source instanceof Button) {
                    Button b = (Button) source;
                    b.setLabel(b.getLabel().toUpperCase());
                }
            };

            ResponsiveUI ui = new ResponsiveUI(changeLabelToUppercaseListener);

            ui.setSize(250, 150);
            ui.setResizable(false);
            ui.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've used a *CountDownLatch* to simplify all the locking system.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class ResponsiveUI extends Frame
{
    private static final CountDownLatch LOCK = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public final Button btn = new Button("abcde");

    public ResponsiveUI()
    {
        add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(ae -> LOCK.countDown());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ResponsiveUI rui = new ResponsiveUI();
        rui.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        rui.setSize(250, 150);
        rui.setResizable(false);
        rui.setVisible(true);
        try {
            LOCK.await();
            String s = rui.btn.getLabel().toUpperCase();
            EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() ->
            {
                rui.btn.setLabel(s);
            });
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error : " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just want to point out that `String s` should be a *local variable* in `main()` which might require slight change in your code (I think it must be `final` in order for `Runnable` to use it?).

Comment: I've moved the `String` to the `main` method, you don't need to make it `final`, the compiler detects that it's "effectively" final so it won't complain.